# javascript multiple forms on the same rendered screen

Tags: javascript

I'm working with classic ASP.

I have an 2 includes that have 2 different forms on them.  They are both unique in name.  However, when I try to read the value of the one the elements in the 2nd form I get an error saying it is null.  However, when I view the source in Firebug I can see that in face there is a value in that element.

My javascript code:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('focusValue').value);
```

Output from firebug:

```
<input id="focusValue" type="hidden" value="1006" name="focusValue">
```

Is there something I need to do because there are 2 forms on this "rendered" screen?  The only other thing I think I should mention is that these pages are in an iFrame.  Not sure if that really matters...

Comment: Can you access it with "document.formname.focusValue.value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iFrame creates a separate document within the containing document, you need to get a reference to that document before you can access its content. There is a reasonable tutorial at http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/.

If you only have one iFrame in the page, then you can reference it by:

```
var frame = window.frames[0];
```

Or you could use an id with *getElementById*. To get a reference to the document:

```
var doc;
if (frame) {
  doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
}
```

Now you can get to the input element:

```
var input = doc && doc.getElementById('focusValue');
```

Of course this all depends on you complying with the same origin policy, otherwise you can't access the frame content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...  I tried doing what you suggested but I'm getting an error: frame.contentWindow is undefined (I've also go the frame.contentDocument is undefined as well).  I will say that when I alert out the "frame" variable that looks right.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't know how you get undefined. If the code is breaking the same domain rule, you don't have access to the content and should get a relevant error. If the iFrame doesn't have a src attribute then there will be a *contentWindow* object (that is empty). If the attribute has an invalid URL, then you may or may not get an access error depending on the browser. But not "undefined". You need to post the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your page, so it's hard to debug. Assuming the script runs AFTER the forms. The only thing i can think is that there is more than one element on the page with the id "focusValue".

What happens when you `console.log(document.getElementById('focusValue'))`

Comment: I get document.getElementById('focusValue') is null